# Heroku scheduler crashing

Tags: heroku, scheduler

I'm having trouble with the scheduler add-on on Heroku. I had it running fine for a long time but now it is stuck in a loop of crashing and restarting.

I've tried stopping the process by running heroku ps:stop scheduler and I've removed the scheduler add-on but it still keeps restarting.

The task it was running was rake:cron. I've since emptied out that task so it's not actually doing anything but it still crashes after running it with the following message:

```
heroku[scheduler.5818]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[scheduler.5818]: State changed from crashed to down
heroku[scheduler.5818]: State changed from down to starting
heroku[scheduler.5818]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake cron`
heroku[scheduler.5818]: State changed from starting to up    
heroku[scheduler.5818]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[scheduler.5818]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[scheduler.5818]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Is there any other way to force kill a process on Heroku? I'm worried I'm being billed for the constantly running/crashed scheduler.

Comment: try to add a ticket to heroku.